# Tenant level mapping to crawled property

Tags: column, site-collection, crawled-property, retention, kql

I have mapped a crawled property ows_DocumentType to RefinableString00 in the SPO Admin console, and I can confirm that all my Site Collections see this mapping.

How do I create the columns on these Site Collections which will hold the DocumentType information and have it crawled as part of ows_DocumentType? When I create a custom column on the Site Collection there is no way of mapping it back to the tenant level mappings.

Do I need to create the column at the Tenant Level and have this selectable by all Site Collections?

Use-case is that we need to apply an auto-label retention policy to all our Site Collections. This uses KQL so would be RefinableString00:Record. So, we need a document type option on all Site Collections which could be set as Record and be attached to the same RefinableString.